# How are orphaned records treated on an Azure Mobile App Service client?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the Azure Mobile App Service. I'm using the soft delete and incremental sync features.

I've run into an interesting edge case:

1. Insert new record into local database
2. Push
3. Record is deleted on the backend. Can be simulated on client by deleting it directly using `client.GetTable<T>().DeleteAsync(foo)` not     `client.GetSyncTable<T>().DeleteAsync(foo)`
4. Local db now has one more record than remote db
5. **Push again**

I assumed the last push would recreate the record on the remote database, but it does not - *this is suprising and very very awesome, as it is the logical result!*

*What I don't understand is, why? How does the client know not to push that orphaned record?*

(Is it because I performed the delete from the client? So in production, when that record would be deleted by our backend systems, the client WOULD push it?)

**EDIT, sorry I didn't explain properly:**
I meant we have backend systems, which may perform the delete directly on the backend database (they don't know of or care about remote clients). I put in point 3 above, just as a "hackish" way to do that from the client itself. Anyway, in such a case, there would be an orphaned record on the client. When this happens, and a push is performed, would the client try to recreate that record on the backend - because it doesn't know the backend deleted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft Delete is how the client knows to delete the "orphaned" record. In other words, the server doesn't actually delete the record, but just marks the deleted flag. Clients that are doing offline sync get deleted records as part of the pull operation and remove those records from the local store. (They do this by adding the __includedDeleted=true flag in the request.)

If the client changes the deleted record and you are using conflict handling (by having a Version field on the client), then the update will be rejected through the regular conflict handling mechanism.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. If our server-side systems directly delete the record (`DELETE FROM [Customer] WHERE ...`), then I'll run into the problem I described above. So what you're saying is that server-side systems must never delete a record, but rather set it's soft delete property?

Comment: That's right. Otherwise you need to purge the client database to get rid of these orphaned records, using PurgeAsync.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sync-table, two tables get created in the local SQLite database - the actual table and a "pending operations" table.  When you do the SyncTable().DeleteAsync(), the record is deleted from the actual table and an entry is placed in the "pending operations" table to delete the record on the backend.  When you do PushAsync(), the pending operations table is used to send the same
requests that would have been sent in the online case.

There are a couple of more complexities than that, but that's the basic gist of what is going on.

If you have access to the underlying SQLite database (for example, you are running a UWP app on Windows), then you can inspect the underlying SQLite database to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry, either I'm misunderstanding you, or I didn't explain myself properly - I think you're describing the "traditional" offline delete case? Added an edit above...

Comment: Ah - I see.  If you know this is going to happen, you use PurgeAsync() on the client to purge either the specific record or all records, then re-sync.   How you tell your clients to do the purge is up to you.   On the same client, you can PurgeAsync() the individual record you are deleting.